# Why is deadlock happening when there are fewer rows in the table

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005

We have a table `TABLEA` whose structure is:

- `ID BINGINT` which is a Primary Key with `IDENTITY(1,1)`
- `PARENTID BIGINT` which is a foreign key column to another table
- And another 17 columns of type `VARCHAR(5)` to `VARCHAR(200)`

There will be millions of rows expected to be present in the table. As SQL server 2005 doesn't have a nice way of inserting multiple rows into a table in one go, I am passing XML into the Stored Procedure which in turn parses the XML and inserts the rows into the table.

The average size of the XML is around 12 items. So load test is using 12 items xml.

The problem I'm having is a deadlock issue happening during the load test. Strange thing is when there are no rows in the table (initially during the load test) deadlocks happen as the load progresses. But if we insert around 10000 rows into the table and then start the load test at the same rate, everything works as expected.

The deadlock error:

> Transaction (Process ID 285) was deadlocked on lock resources with another process and has been chosen as the deadlock victim. Rerun the transaction

The query used to insert the records from parsing the XML (the XML is going to have 13 items in it):

```
DECLARE @items_xml TABLE (data XML)
DECLARE @p_parent_id BIGINT
DECLARE @p_items_xml_array XML

SET @p_parent_id = 438906

SET @p_condition_entry_array = N'<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>    <Items xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"><Item></Item></Items>'
INSERT INTO @items_xml(data)
SELECT @p_items_xml_array

INSERT INTO TABLEA WITH (ROWLOCK)
(PARENTID, COLUMN1, COLUMN2, COLUMN3, COLUMN4, COLUMN5, COLUMN6, COLUMN7,
COLUMN8, COLUMN9, COLUMN10, COLUMN11,COLUMN12,  COLUMN13, COLUMN14,       COLUMN15, COLUMN16,COLUMN17)
SELECT
  @p_parent_id AS PARENTID,
  t.c.value('@F1[1]', 'VARCHAR(32)') AS COLUMN1,
  t.c.value('@F2[1]', 'VARCHAR(32)') AS COLUMN2,
  t.c.value('@F3[1]', 'VARCHAR(3)') AS COLUMN3,
  t.c.value('@F4[1]', 'VARCHAR(32)') AS COLUMN4,
  t.c.value('@F5[1]', 'VARCHAR(200)') AS COLUMN5,
  t.c.value('@F61]', 'VARCHAR(20)') AS COLUMN6,
  t.c.value('@F7[1]', 'VARCHAR(3)') AS COLUMN7,
  t.c.value('@F8[1]', 'VARCHAR(8)') AS COLUMN8,
  t.c.value('@F9[1]', 'VARCHAR(3)') AS COLUMN9,
  t.c.value('@F10[1]', 'VARCHAR(8)') AS COLUMN10,
  t.c.value('@F11[1]', 'VARCHAR(3)') AS COLUMN11,
  t.c.value('@F12[1]', 'VARCHAR(3)') AS COLUMN12,
  t.c.value('@F13[1]', 'VARCHAR(32)') AS COLUMN13,
  t.c.value('@F14[1]', 'VARCHAR(200)') AS COLUMN14,
  t.c.value('@F15[1]', 'VARCHAR(20)') AS COLUMN15,
  t.c.value('@F16[1]', 'VARCHAR(10)') AS COLUMN16,
  t.c.value('@F17[1]', 'VARCHAR(32)') AS COLUMN17,
FROM @conditionEntries AS a
CROSS APPLY a.data.nodes('Items/Item') AS t(c)
```

**My question is:** Why are deadlocks happening when there are not many rows in the table and why the deadlocks don't happen when the table already contains many rows? I have used the ROWLOCK hint, but it is not helping.

Comment: SQL may apply different level of locking depending on various conditions, including number of rows in the table. [Capture deadlock information](http://sqlmag.com/database-performance-tuning/gathering-deadlock-information-deadlock-graph) to see exactly what happened.

Comment: Yes, the above query will get executed inside a transaction. But there is no loop. Each time SP gets executed it tries to parse the xml and insert rows. Usually the XML will have 12 items, so 12 rows.

Comment: In general deadlocks are associated with heavy load data because it means (in general) the time the transaction remain open for long times but If you think on deadlocks as transactions collisions another way to increase the "collision" rate is increasing the chance of using the same row/page in two distinct transactions.

Comment: You have multiple processes inserting data, correct? Do you select some records from TABLEA inside transaction, before inserting new ones?

Comment: Yes, I do. There is a SELECT query to figure out weather a  given record is present or not. Depending on that either row will be inserted or updated.

Comment: Then you must apply proper locking when selecting these rows @Ranganatha, which would be `updlock` if you're only interested in existing rows or `updlock, holdlock` if you're also concerned about possible future rows that match the `where` condition.

Comment: "As SQL server 2005 doesn't have a nice of inserting multiple rows into a table in one go," Really? Look [here](https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/learn-sql-server/bulk-inserts-via-tsql-in-sql-server/) and [here](https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/reporting-services/using-sql-server-integration-services-to-bulk-load-data/) and [here](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd425070(v=sql.100).aspx) for an intro to bulk loading data into sql server.

Comment: Also look at the [SQLBulkCopy](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlbulkcopy(v=vs.90).aspx) class in the .NET class library if you need to load data quickly from a .NET app